# How to Reorder menus (not menu items)

Tags: navigation

I have the standard Main Menu, Management Menu, User Menu, etc., plus a bunch of custom menus. They are consistently shown in the same strange order (not in the order created, not alpha, not alpha by machine name) when shown in /admin/structure/menu/manage/. I can't determine a logic for the order.

I use [Footer sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/footer_sitemap) to place links in the footer and the various menus show up in this same order. I can find no way to change the weight of entire menus or reorder them. The database table I found was sorted alphabetically by machine name and not in the order I see at /admin/structure/menu/manage/. Any way to control this order?

Comment: Which version of Drupal?

Comment: Drupal 7. Current version.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try the alternative module [Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_map). They fixed the ordering issue in their latest version (7.x-1.3).